# Read from SQL Server with Python using few parameters from DataFrame

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas, sqlite

I need to read from SQl Server Database using this parameters:

- period of time from uploaded Dataframe (date of order and date after month)
- clients id from the same Dataframe

So I have something like this:

```
sql_sales = """
SELECT 
    dt,
    clientID, 
    cost
WHERE 
    dt between %(date1)s AND %(date2)s
    AND kod in %(client)s
"""
```

And I have df with columns:

1. clientsID
2. date of order
3. date after month

I can use list of clients but the code should parsed database with a few lists of paramenters (two of them is a part of period).

```
sales = sales.append(pd.read_sql(sql_sales, conn, params={'client':df['clientsID].tolist()}))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I got something similar to work in the past was to do `in {}` and then use `.format` with the parameters listed in order. Also, then you don't need to use the `params` argument. Finally, if you are using `IN` with SQL, then in Python you need to create a `tuple` from the client list. For the line `dt between {} AND {}`, you may also be able to do `dt between ? AND ?`.

```
client = tuple(df['clientsID'].tolist())

sql_sales = """
SELECT 
dt,
clientID, 
cost
WHERE 
dt between {} AND {}
AND kod in {}
""".format(date1,date2,client)

sales = sales.append(pd.read_sql(sql_sales, conn))
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I have a questions about **date1,date2**, should I add it in the list like **client** with `tuple`?

Comment: @Valeria , you shouldn't need to.